# How do I recognize a rotated digit in an image using OpenCV 3 and Tesseract/Template Matching?

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Here is my problem. I have some simple images where there are some big black digits inside a green circle. The problem is that they can be randomly rotated. What I managed to do so far is to identify the green circles and then cut them from the image, so that I end up with just the digits.
In order to straighten them up I thought to construct a rotated bounding rect in the following way:

- first I find all the contours of the digit with `cv::findContours`
- then for each digit contour I construct the best fitting rotated rectangle which contains the digit via the function `cv::minAreaRect`

Everything works just fine, except in the case of digit `4`, whose rotated rectangle is not aligned with the number but slightly tilted, as you can see in the images below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gykct.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN1Cc.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwjV.png]

I tried using a fitting ellipse as well, but that is tilted too. The only solution I can think of is to use template matching, providing templates which are themselves rotated as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the typeface of the numbers is consistent, and if you can isolate the circles, and if they are (or can be made to be) a uniform size, then you might be able to bypass Tesseract completely at the cost of constructing templates for all of the numbers in a variety of rotations.

Assuming that applying a template gives a decent signal if it's within +/- 2°, that's be (360/5)*10 = 720 templates to cover 0-9. It'd be interesting to benchmark the cost of applying those templates against the cost of a Tesseract invocation.